# Assigning to nested list with list of indices

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, nested-lists

Given a nested list, you can access the elements with something like

```
data = [[12, 15], [21, 22], [118, 546], [200, 1200]]

assert data[0][0] == 12
```

The issue is that in this case, I want to index into a nested list with a "list of indexes", with dynamic at runtime length. For example, the "list of indexes" for above would be [0,0]

I want this general type of function

```
def nested_list_assignment(nested_list, list_of_indices, value):
```

and would work something like

```
# passes this basic test
data = [[12, 15], [21, 22], [118, 546], [200, 1200]]

assert data[0][0] == 12
nested_list_assignment(data, [0, 0], 0)
assert data[0][0] == 0
```

I have a working impl like

```
def nested_list_assignment(nested_list, list_of_indices, value):
    # ill handle this case later
    assert len(list_of_indices) > 0

    if len(list_of_indices) == 1:
        nested_list[list_of_indices[0]] = value
    else:
        nested_list_assignment(nested_list[list_of_indices[0]], list_of_indices[1:], value)
```

but I'm curious if Python gives any constructs for this, or just a standard library function for this in general.

Comment: There's nothing built into Python, but it's [common in Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Comment: @Mark cant use anything except standard lib for this, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard Python function or operator for this, but something like this works generically as long as you're sure that everything being indexed is itself indexable with the elements of `indices`:

```
def list_assignment(indexable, indices, value):
    for i in indices[:-1]:
        indexable = indexable[i]
    indexable[indices[-1]] = value


data = [[12, 15], [21, 22], [118, 546], [200, 1200]]
list_assignment(data, [0, 0], 0)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 15], [21, 22], [118, 546], [200, 1200]]
```

This works for anything you can index:

```
d = { 
    'a': {
        'b': 1,
        'c': 2,
    },
    'd': 3
}

list_assignment(d, ['a', 'c'], 42)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 42}, 'd': 3}
```

Keep in mind that this can go wrong in several ways:

- an empty list of indices fails
- a list with too many indices, or missing indices, fails

Answer (score 2):

Building on Grismar's answer, for convenience this can be implemented using `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. methods. For example:

```
class Nested:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def __getitem__(self, t):
        x = self.data[t[0]]
        for i in t[1:]:
            x = x[i]
        return x
    
    def __setitem__(self, t, val):
        x = self.data
        for i in t[:-1]:
            x = x[i]
        x[t[-1]] = val
```

Then one can use it as follows:

```
data = [[12, 15], [21, 22], [118, 546], [200, 1200]]
data = Nested(data)

print(data[2, 1])
```

It gives:

```
546
```

Assignments:

```
data[2, 1] = 100
print(data[2, 1])
```

It gives:

```
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Hope this would be helpful.

```
def nested_list_assignment(nested_list, list_of_indices, value):
    L = len(list_of_indices)
    s = nested_list
    for i in range(L):
        s = s[list_of_indices[i]]
        if i == L-2:s[list_of_indices[L-2]] = value; break
    return nested_list`
```